# Cocos2dx issue crash app when clear memory

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

When application only close, it's okay.
But When I set alarm and clear device memory. after time it will show on android but when I click on button process dismiss (It will also process in c++), then app was crash with message.

```
06-06 14:00:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-06 14:00:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(29671): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity.onFinished:(I)V
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is a sub-class of the LinkageError class and denotes that the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared as native. Have you explicitly specified the native library that you're using?